# How to add a self-signed SSL certificate to your website

Tags: ssl, ftp, built-in-web-server

I have a site and I have a development subdomain I want to assign a self-signed certificate to it so I can test a login portal, I will consider buying an actual SSL certificate for my real domain, I host my site with 1and1.co.uk. I use FTP to connect.

Comment: There is nothing easier than adding a self-signed SSL certificate to a web-site. The question is why on earth you would want to do so?

Comment: I want to test a login portal (if it's secure)

Comment: Many hosting provider does support self signed certificate. You can contact hosting provider support for self signed certificate for your website and sub domain.

Comment: I'm using 1and1 who don't